# How to Package and Publish a Script That Calls Other Scripts as a Pip Wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel, distribute

I'm trying to create wheel for scripts generated with bazel `py_binary` rule, and encountered some problem.

I try to give a minor example of the problem. I have a directory like this:

```
.
├── MANIFEST.in
├── bin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mytest
│   └── mytest.lib
│       ├── used1
│       └── used2
└── setup.py
```

where `bin/mytest.lib` contains many scripts, and `bin/mytest` is the entry of this package, calling all the scripts in `bin/mytest.lib`. It could look like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

bash $0.lib/used1
bash $0.lib/used2
```

I write a `setup.py` to create a wheel:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="mytest",
    version="0.0.1",
    maintainer="",
    maintainer_email="",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[],
    scripts=["bin/mytest"],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

and `MANIFEST.in` tries to get **all** files in `bin`:

```
graft bin
```

Then, I `python setup.py bdist_wheel` and `pip install dist/mytest-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`.

I tried to use `mytest` but failed as `MY_ENV/bin/mytest.lib/used1` doesn't exist. (Here `MY_ENV` == `/home/dev/conda_dev/devenv/Linux/envs/devenv-3.8-c`)

There are 2 major problems:

1. `mytest.lib` is in `MY_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bin` rather than `MY_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mytest-0.0.1.dist-info/bin`
2. `mytest` actually expects `mytest.lib` be in `MY_ENV/bin` rather than `MY_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mytest-0.0.1.dist-info/bin` or other directories.

If I cannot modify `mytest` or `mytest.lib` as they are generated by bazel (but I can add something if needed), how can I make `mytest` available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inspired from `flask8` and create such a workaround:

I change directory to

```
.
├── mytest
│   ├── entry.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mytest
│   ├── mytest.lib
│   │   ├── used1
│   │   └── used2
│   └── tmp.md
└── setup.py
```

so that I'll get `MY_ENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mytest`.

I put `mytest.py` as entry_points, my setup.py currently looks like:

```py
import setuptools

__version__ = "0.0.1"

setuptools.setup(
    name="mytest",
    version=__version__,
    maintainer="",
    maintainer_email="",
    packages=["mytest"],
    install_requires=[],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['mytest = mytest.entry:entry']
    },
    package_data={'mytest': ['**/*']},
)
```

and in `entry`, I call `mytest` script:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def entry():
    argv = sys.argv[1:]
    dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    script = os.path.join(dir, "mytest")
    subprocess.run([script, *argv])
```

It's currently working well for me, but I don't know whether this is a good solution. I'm looking forward to any better solutions :)